# Python Accessing Dictionary and changing values - Error

Tags: python, dictionary

I cannot seem to figure this out, and, It's diving my crazy. Let's assume I have the following class:

```
class Test:

 connect = {'Message': None}

 def connect(self):
  if not self.connect['Message']:
     print "Message is not set"
  else:
     print "Message is active and set!"

 def connectMSG(self, theMessage):
     self.connect['Message'] = theMessage
```

The following looks ok. I can't seem to visually see an error however, I get the following:

> self.connect['Message'] = theMessage
>   TypeError: 'instancemethod' object does not support item assignment

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

You're overwritimg the attribute `connect` by the method with the same name. Rename your attribute.

The next question would be, if you really want to have a class attribute or an instance attribute. If you want an instance attribute define it in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Omg, I'm so stupid sometimes!!!! Thank you so very much aha, It's really early in the morning and I think I need to go back to sleep =)

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a method and a variable with the same name `connect`. So you have overwritten your dictionary with your method, change the name of one of them.

So what is happing is that first you create the dictionary with name connect, but then you override it with a method. When you try to access the dictionary what you are get is an error telling you that `connect` method does not support that operation (it is not a dict)

Answer (score 0):

**Corrections are:**

```
class Connection:
   def __init__(self):
       self.connect = {'Message': None}              #moved here

   def Check(self):                                  #renamed
       if not self.connect['Message']:
           print "Message is not set."
       else:
           print "Message is active and set!"

   def Connect(self, theMessage):                    #renamed
       self.connect['Message'] = theMessage

cnt = Connection()
```

Comment: This is one of the many corrections that you can do for fixing the code. However, your code is not pythonic, PEP8 specifies that method name should be *lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability*, and if you change the code to follow PEP8 you will face the same problem.